# How to handle multiple processes Merging to same snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake and multiple jobs would need to merge records to the snowflake table. how can duplicates be avoided during this process? How to make sure that multiple merges happen one after another.

Comment: writes to the same table block each other, like in most DB's to you don't get duplicats, but you do get stalled code, which you are paying for. Thus if two warehouses/tasks are wait on each other that costs worst case 3 units of cost, for 2 units of work (the first costs 1, while the seconds wait for 1 unit, then works for 1 unit).

Answer (score 1):

Use dependent task trees to guarantee they are executed in the order you want

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#simple-tree-of-tasks